# How to update value in sql without using the WHERE condition

Tags: sql

The syntax to update a table is:

```
UPDATE country
SET country_name = 'america'
WHERE condition;
```

For example:
I have a country table with 3 columns: `continent`, `country_id` and `country_name`.
In `continent` and `country_id`, all the values are still yet to be completed and are still set to null (the value is set to `varchar(256)`).
In column of country_name I have "australia", "usa", "japan", "canada".

How do I UPDATE "usa" to "america" without using the WHERE condition?

Comment: The answer is, you probably don't.  What is preventing your from using the `WHERE` clause when updating?  Which database are you using?

Comment: It is impossible.

Comment: @Jens We could use a trick, e.g. define a CTE which applies the `WHERE` restriction and then blindly update that CTE.  But this is probably out of scope for the OP.

Comment: i understand without the WHERE condition, all the countries listed in the country_name will all change to america. but since i don't have any value in country_id to set the WHERE condition, can you please confirm if there's a way to UPDATE the value from usa to america?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not allowed to use `where` for some kind of theoretical exercise, you could use `case`:

```
update  country
set     country_name = case
                       when country_name = 'usa' then 'america' 
                       else country_name
                       end
```

This will update every row, but it'll only change the value for 'usa'.

Answer (score 1):

I understood from your comments that you can use where but you can't use the country_id field so probably this is what you need.

```
UPDATE country
SET country_name = 'america'
WHERE country_name = 'usa';
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically pass arguments into a stored procducer

```
CREATE PROC sp_UpdateExistingValues

@input varchar(10),
@deptName varchar(10)

AS
 
  UPDATE #TEMPTABLE    
  SET DEPARTMENT = 
  CASE WHEN NAME=@input THEN @deptName 
  ELSE DATEPART
  
END
```